# How to get original size of image in imageFallback Magento?

Tags: magento, resize

How to get the original size of image in imageFallback? I used the below code to get the images.

My code:

```
echo $imageFallback['image_fallback'];
```

Return:

```
http:\/\/www.xxxxxx.com\/media\/catalog\/product\/cache\/6\/image\/500x800\/602f0fa2c1f0d1b8sa098a09s9856ff9\/c\/o\/car1.png
```

But i need return the original file, without resize:

Ex:

```
http:\/\/www.xxxxxx.com\/media\/catalog\/product\/c\/o\/car1.png
```

Thank you

Comment: it looks like you're using some kind of extension. there is no image_fallback in magento default.

Comment: hi, this function have in file app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\configurableswatches\catalog\media\js.phtml --- magento 1.9.2.2

Comment: $imageFallback['product'] is the actual product, so you could write something like  foreach ($imageFallback['product']->getMediaGalleryImages() as $image) { and try to go from there